# Relation between impedance and phase angle in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I am seeing a lot the expression that the phase angle $\theta$ between the current and the voltage of the circuit can be expressed in term $tan\theta=\frac{IM(Z)}{Re(Z)}$ when $Z$ is the total impedance of the circuit, and I do not understand why is it true? what is the logic behind it? I understand that $Z$ is complex number and I understand the relation $tan\theta=\frac{IM(Z)}{Re(Z)}$ but why this angle is represent the phase angle between current and the voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an RLC series circuit with an AC source of voltage, the current in the circuit, $i(t)$, can be written as the real part of

$$
{\bf I} = I_0e^{j\omega t}\,, 
$$
where $j = \sqrt{-1}$ and the source voltage, $v(t)$, can be written as the real part of ${\bf V} = V_0e^{j(\omega t + \theta)}\,,$ where $V_0 = I_0 Z$. This means that

$$
{\bf V} = {\bf I}{\rm {\bf Z}}\,,
$$
where ${\rm {\bf Z}} = Ze^{j\theta}$ is the impedance. The angle $\theta$ is the phase difference between $i(t)$ and $v(t)$. The impedance can be expressed in terms of the resistance, inductance and capacitance of the circuit as
$$
{\rm {\bf Z}} = R + j(\omega L - 1/(\omega C))\,.
$$
This follows from applying Kirchhoff's voltage law to the circuit, which says that
$$
{\bf V} = {\bf V}_{R} + {\bf V}_L + {\bf V}_C\,.
$$
The expressions for ${\bf V}_{R}$,  ${\bf V}_L$ and ${\bf V}_C$ are
${\bf V}_{R} = {\bf I}R, {\bf V}_{L} = j\omega L {\bf I}$ and ${\bf V}_{C} = -j(\omega C)^{-1}{\bf I}$ respectively.

Using the properties of complex numbers and applying them to ${\rm {\bf Z}}$ it follows that

$$
|{\rm {\bf Z}}| = Z = \sqrt{R^2 + (\omega L - 1/(\omega C))^2}\,,\quad \tan\theta = \frac{Im({\rm {\bf Z}})}{Re({\rm {\bf Z}})}\,.
$$

A similar analysis can be applied to an RLC AC circuit with components connected in parallel to obtain the same result but in that case, the expression for ${\rm {\bf Z}}$ differs from the expression above.

${\bf Edit:}$ As mentioned in the comments, the example involving the RLC series circuit given above, it looks like the voltage of the source depends on the current. However, this not actually the case. To make this fact clearer, let us write

$$t = t^{\prime} - \frac{\theta}{\omega}$$

and substitute it into the expressions for ${\bf V}$ and ${\bf I}$ written above. Doing so yields the following expressions for ${\bf V}$ and ${\bf I}$

$$
{\bf V} = V_0e^{j\omega t^{\prime}}\,, \quad {\bf I} = I_0e^{j(\omega t^{\prime} - \theta)}\,. 
$$
In these expressions involving the time variable $t^{\prime}$ one can drop the prime on the $t^{\prime}$ if one so wishes.

Taking the ratio of ${\bf V}$ to ${\bf I}$ yields,

$$
\frac{{\bf V}}{{\bf I}} = \frac{V_0}{I_{0}}e^{j\theta} = Ze^{j\theta} = {\rm {\bf Z}}
$$
where $Z$ and $\tan\theta$  have the same expressions as stated above.

Comment: Note that *typically*, the voltage source here would be the zero phase reference

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: In books I've read, for example, "Electricity and Magnetism" (4th edition) by W. E. Duffin and "Electricity and Magnetism" (3rd edition) by Bleaney and Bleaney, the expressions for the voltage and current phasors I've used for a series circuit are employed. Bleaney and Bleaney also state that one can use ${\bf V} = V_0e^{j\phi}$ which means ${\bf I} = I_0e^{j(\omega t - \phi)}\,.$ So I agree with you.

Comment: Physics_Et_Al, let me refine the point I wish to make. In this *particular* circuit, the voltage source *fixes* the voltage across the RLC circuit while the current magnitude and phase are dependent variables. By writing the current as you have, the phase of the voltage across 'looks' like a dependent variable.

Comment: Alfred Centauri, okay but if one looks at the books I mention and some university physics textbooks that cover a broad range of topics, for example, Sears and Zemansky's "University Physics with Modern Physics" by Young and Freedman or "University Physics, Revised Edition" by H. Benson, one sees $i(t) = I_0\cos(\omega t), v(t) = V_0\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ or $i(t) = I_0\sin(\omega t), v(t) = V_0\sin(\omega t + \phi)$  so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Alfred Centauri, maybe it does 'look' like the voltage depends on the current but it is the voltage source that results in the current in the RLC circuit example.

Comment: There is a typo in my first message: it should read ${\bf V} = V_0e^{j\omega t}$ and not ${\bf V} = V_0e^{j\phi}\,.$ I did not notice it until now Aggh!!

Comment: I think it doesn't really matter because one just has to redefine the argument of the voltage to get the desired format. For example, letting $t = t^{\prime} - \phi/\omega$ gives ${\bf V} = V_0e^{j\omega t^{\prime}}$ and ${\bf I} = I_0e^{j(\omega t^{\prime} - \phi)}\,,$ which is the format required.

Comment: Physics_Et_Al, no worries, I knew what you meant from the context. For what it's worth, I pulled down my old undergraduate physics textbook (Ohanian, *Physics*, 2nd ed), and the voltage source driven series RLC example puts the phase term in the current rather than the voltage variable. *Mathematically*, it doesn't matter. But, thinking about this as a system with a stimulus (independent variable) and response (dependent variable), it seems quite odd *conceptually* (to me) put the dependent phase variable with the independent voltage phasor.

Comment: Alfred Centauri, I agree that conceptually it does seem quite odd to put the phase variable in the independent voltage phasor. I admit that I have not thought about that aspect of it.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that Z is complex number and I understand the relation
> $\tan\theta=\frac{\mathfrak{Im}(Z)}{\mathfrak{Re}(Z)}$ but why this angle is represent the phase angle
> between current and the voltage?

The impedance $Z$ of the circuit is the ratio of the *[phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor)* voltage $\tilde{V}$ across the circuit to the *phasor* current $\tilde{I}$ through the circuit.

$$Z=\frac{\tilde{V}}{\tilde{I}}=\frac{Ve^{i\theta_V}}{Ie^{i\theta_I}}=\frac{V}{I}e^{i(\theta_V-\theta_I)}=\frac{V}{I}e^{i\theta}=\frac{V}{I}\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right),\quad\theta=\theta_V-\theta_I$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a voltage $V(t)$ and a current $I(t)$ in an AC circuit.
Both rotate with the same frequency $\omega$.
In general they have different phases $\phi_V$ and $\phi_I$.
So we have
$$\begin{align}
V(t)&=V_0\ e^{j(\omega t+\phi_V)} \\
I(t)&=I_0\ e^{j(\omega t+\phi_I)}
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

The definition of impedance $Z$ is
$$Z=\frac{V(t)}{I(t)}. \tag{2}$$
It is a complex number
$$Z=\text{Re}(Z) + j\ \text{Im}(Z)$$
Using $\hat{Z}=\sqrt{(\text{Re}(Z))^2+(\text{Im}(Z)^2}$
and $\tan\theta=\frac{\text{Im}(Z)}{\text{Re}(Z)}$
this can be rewritten as
$$Z=\hat{Z}\ e^{j\theta} \tag{3}$$

Inserting equations (1) and (3) into (2) we get
$$\hat{Z}\ e^{j\theta}
 =\frac{V_0\ e^{j(\omega t+\phi_V)}}{I_0\ e^{j(\omega t+\phi_I)}}
 =\frac{V_0}{I_0}e^{j(\phi_V-\phi_I)}
\tag{4}$$
Comparing the left and the right side of (4) we immediately see
$$\begin{align}
\hat{Z}&=\frac{V_0}{I_0} \\
\theta&=\phi_V-\phi_I
\end{align}$$
So we have found that the angle $\theta$ of the impedance
is the phase difference $(\phi_V-\phi_I)$ between voltage and current.